# Как реализовать вертикальную навигацию с миниатюрами в Swiper?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, слайдер, swiper

Прошу вас помочь мне с вертикальным режимом для навигации в Swiper.

САБЖ: необходимо реализовать вертикальную навигацю с миниатюрами на Свайпер.
УСЛОВИЯ: Миниатюра и соотвествующий ей слайд - повязаны.
Есть стрелки для листания Миниатюр.

ПРОБЛЕМЫ:

1. Плагин не хочет показывать в ВЕРТИКАЛЬНОМ режиме столько миниатюр, сколько я его прошу. Они постоянно распяливают контейнер.
2. Миниатюры и слайды связаны однобоко - При листании слайдера не листается список с миниатюрами.
3. Список в синматюрами может "уехать" не понять куда.

[Потрогать больного](https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/ExxoGmE)

Прошу укажите, что я сделала не так или предложите вариант решения. 
К сожалению сменить плагин я не могу. Он юзается в большом проекте.(

ЗАРАНЕЕ БЛАГОДАРЮ!

```js
var galleryTop = new Swiper(".product__galery-wrap", {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs
  }
});
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper(".product__thumbs", {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  direction:'vertical',
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }
});
```

```css
.product__slider {
  width: 48%;
}

.product__galery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: auto;
}

.product__galery-wrap {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.product__thumbs-wrap {
  width: 60px;
}

.product__thumbs-pic {
  flex: 0 1 60px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/godlike.css/3.6.2/godlike.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="product__slider">
  <div class="product__galery">
    <div class="swiper-container product__galery-wrap">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper product__galery-list">
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__galery-img"><img src="img/catalog/video" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container product__thumbs">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper product__thumbs-list">
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="img/catalog/video.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide product__thumbs-pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6" alt=""></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product__share">
  </div>
</div>
```